# iOS canOpenURL always returns false

Tags: ios, swift

I have to check 5 chat app wheter they are installed or not. These apps are:

- Messenge
- Instagram
- Telegram
- Viber
- WhatsApp

In my Info.plist added the following lines:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>instagram</string>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
  <string>viber</string>
  <string>fb-messenger</string>
  <string>telegram</string>
</array>
```

But canOpenURL always returns false (apps are installed)

```
// let appScheme = "\(appName)://app"
// let appScheme = "\(appName)://test"
let appScheme = "\(appName)://"
let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme)
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl!)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Tried the solutions from other questions, but none of the seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please check following code I hope it will solve your problem, I have attach some scheme of other social network

```
enum SocialType
{
    case twitter
    case fb
    case whatsapp
    // MARK: -
    case viber

//    as for now (26.03.2017), I found this URI are working:
//
//    viber://add?number=NUMBER - open user page
//    viber://forward?text=foo - share text with selected users
//    viber://chats - opens chat tab
//    viber://calls - opens calls tab
//    ??? - can't find how to open user's/contacts tab
//    viber://public - opens a public tab
//    viber://more - open more tab (the last one in the row)
    // MARK: -
    
    // MARK: -
    case telegram
//    This is a wrong tg:// format. Currently, official Telegram clients support these formats:
//
//    tg://join?invite=
//
//    tg://addstickers?set=
//
//    tg://msg_url?
//
//    tg://confirmphone?
//
//    tg://socks?
//
//    tg://proxy?
//
//    tg://resolve/?domain=
    // MARK: -
    case instragram
    case none
}
func openURLName(types: SocialType.none, Username: String)
{
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    var finalWebrul: URL?
    if types == .instragram
    {
        let Username =  "instagram" // Your Instagram Username here
        let appURL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=\(Username)")!
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        
        if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
            application.open(appURL)
        } else {
            // if Instagram app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
            let webURL = URL(string: "https://instagram.com/\(Username)")!
            application.open(webURL)
        }
    }
    else if types == .fb
    {
        let appURL = URL(string: "fb://profile/\(Username)")!
        finalWebrul = appURL
        
        if application.canOpenURL(finalWebrul) {
            application.open(finalWebrul)
        }
    }
    else if types == .twitter
    {
        let screenName =  "NJMINISTRIESINC"
        let appURL = URL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=\(screenName)")!
        let webURL = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(screenName)")!
        
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appURL)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL)
            }
        } else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Twitter
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(webURL)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL)
            }
        }
    }
    else if types == .whatsapp
    {
        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=" + Username
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL)
                } else {
                    print("Install Whatsapp")
                    let whatsappString = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + Username
                    if let whatsappURL = URL(string: whatsappString){
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: according to his question, auther said how app will identify social network app installed or not so I have posted social network url scheme of them

Comment: @Chandaboy might be worth mentioning that OP's original code didn't work because they were using incorrect URLs, not because of actual code issues. Both questions and answers should be useful for future readers as well, not just OP.